# We three or us three

Tags: subjects, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, nonfinite-verbs, objective-case

Does the subject value in the following example need to be "us" or "we". Does it follow the same principle in pluralising the subject where removing one component isolates the correct noun?

> Dad and I have been discussing the possibility of we three getting away for a weekend together.

Comment: Would you say *the possibility of **us** getting away* or *the possibility of **we** getting away*?

Answer (score 2):

You use the nominative inflections of personal pronouns like *I, he, we* only for subjects of finite verbs like *gets* or *got*.

To provide a subject to a nonfinite verb like *getting* or *to get* as you are attempting to do here, you must use the accusative case pronouns like *me, him, us*.

That means you can only talk about us getting away, never about we getting away.